# Get an incrementing number in Logic App Select

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am using a Logic App to transform some data for an integration. I am trying to avoid using For Each loops as the amount of data I am working with is high, and these incur a cost for each action and iteration of the for each loop.

However the integration I am working with requires a unique incrementing number for each line. They don't have to be sequential, or even starting with 1 but the order should be kept the same.

[image: Logic App Flow]

So with the above, the first one would get LineNumber 1, the second LineNumber 2, etc.. (or like I said, it could be 67829, 67835, etc..)

I tried to set a variable with `ticks(utcNow())` before the start of the mapping, and then use `sub(ticks(utcNow()), variables('startTicks'))` but this is evaluated once and the same number is applied to all.

My next thought is to use an azure function/inline javascript to go through afterward and assign them, but just wondering if there is a way to accomplish this in the select.

Comment: Not inside select, but you can send a StartLineNumber in the `data` itself for each item from the api call which you make. Because this way (using select) will require a loop definitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*or like I said, it could be 67829, 67835, etc..*

Answering to this requirement,

Inside the Select Option :

```
indexOf(string(variables('<DATA Variable>')),string(item()))
```

[image]

**Explanation :**

item() - current item (of all items) in the select - stringified the same & tried to find the same in stringified version of the entire data - the index number will be returned.

### OUTPUT

[image]

[image]

**Please note :**

- Did not get a chance to check on a very large dataset.
- This may fail, if a specific row(all values in the row) repetitive in nature - I assume this may not
  be your case (order number might unique )